# type numbers when shift key is pressed vb.net

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, keyboard-events, keyboard-hook

i am using vb.net to edit a gridview value and when shift is pressed i want to edit multiple cellvalues that belong to a group in the same time, now my problem is when shift is pressed and i click a number key it will give me a symbole

for example

```
  SHIFT+1 = !
  SHIFT+2 = @
  and so on
```

However i want it to be

```
SHIFT+1 = 1
SHIFT+2 = 2
and so on
```

is there a built in functionality to do this?

if not, then i think i need to write a function to do this which functions as when `shift+1` is pressed then keyboard inpt is `1` and not `!`

any ideas on how achive such behavior in vb.net?
and don't tell me to use ctrl because i am using it for another thing already and it won't type when using ctrl :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a naive routine such as this. If you need comma etc, modify as needed:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.Shift AndAlso
       (Keys.KeyCode And e.KeyData) >= Keys.D1 AndAlso
       (Keys.KeyCode And e.KeyData) <= Keys.D9 Then

        TextBox1.SelectedText = ChrW((Keys.KeyCode And e.KeyData))
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True

    End If
End Sub
```